# Limit journalctl to single user or process

Tags: journalctl

When troubleshooting script ran by Apache, I use the following:

```
journalctl -f -uhttpd
```

When executed on the command line, under my normal username I  first do:

```
php testing_new_socket_server.php
```

and then in another terminal use the following:

```
journalctl -f
```

On the machine in question, I have a PHP based server running under a different user than myself and set up using systemctl with unit name `phpsocketserver.service` which is making a lot of chatter to journalctl and I don't want to see the log associated with it.

How can I just see the log associated with `testing_new_socket_server.php`?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the output to lines matching some logged field by adding *field=value* items to the command, eg to see logs from process 11333 only:

```
journalctl -f _PID=11333
```

The fields are listed in [man systemd.journal-fields](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html).

Comment: I think using  **_COMM=, _EXE=, _CMDLINE=**  fields are what he needs, but what you pointed out is the right approach.